# Pyside, PyQt4: How to set a validator when editing a cell in a QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, qtableview

In QLineEdit objects I can set a RegExp validator like this:

```
validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(QtCore.QRegExp("\d{11}"), lineedit)
lineedit.setValidator(validator)
```

How can I set a similar validator when I edit a cell on a QTableView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By subclassing QStyledItemDelegate and reimplementing the createEditor method:

```
class ValidatedItemDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, widget, option, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return 0
        if index.column() == 0: #only on the cells in the first column
            editor = QtGui.QLineEdit(widget)
            validator = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(QtCore.QRegExp("\d{11}"), editor)
            editor.setValidator(validator)
            return editor
        return super(ValidatedItemDelegate, self).createEditor(widget, option, index)
```

Then you can set the validator like this:

```
tableview.setItemDelegate(ValidatedItemDelegate())
```